# How to create event&listener to check if there is specific file in folder

Tags: php, laravel, events, listener

I want to listen for example storage directory is specific file created and if it is to do something. How to create listen and event class to do that?

Comment: is [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) what you need?

Comment: @hungrykoala, I need listener that will check with this function is file created, but as a listener that will notify me that file is created.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.setInterval(function() {

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.example.com/somefile.ext',
    type: 'HEAD',
    error: function() {
        //file not exists
    },
    success: function() {
        //file exists
    }
});

        }, 5000); // you can change this time interval as you want
```

> code for checking 404 status,

```
    function UrlExists(url) {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open('HEAD', url, false);
        http.send();
        return http.status != 404;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The file is **-for sure-** created on PHP side.
So there is a specific code chunk which does that.

So you know where to start.

Now when the file is created, depending on where, when and how you want the "confirmation" to be stored or displayed... There is **MANY options**.

I suggest you to read about [PHP `file_put_content`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-put-contents.php).
Find it in the code you have and try something.